# What is the fastest spaceship configuration?

Tags: freeciv

Spaceships in Freeciv are built out of Space Modules, Space Structural, and Space Components. Which combination of the parts result in a spaceship that takes the least amount of time to reach Alpha Centauri?

This is what I have attempted (travel time is 7.7 years):

[image: Freeciv spaceship]

Is that the fastest possible spaceship?

Comment: You mean you have copied [this ship](https://freeciv.fandom.com/wiki/Forum:Where_do_I_choose_what_kind_of_spaceship_module%3F)? Or that that's your reference? Also: isn't that part of the game, to figure that out?

Comment: @Joachim No, that spaceship is slower (7.9 years vs. 7.7 years for mine).